# Power BI ODBC - How select schema

Tags: odbc, teradata, powerbi-desktop

Good afternoon,

We use odbc connector to access our Teradata (we use the TTU 15) and we are looking for a simple solution allowing to select the SCHEMA directly from the ODBC connection when doing a "GET DATA" from Power BI Desktop.

Why ? Because people who are using PBI does not have SQL knowledge and it takes more than 1 minutes to display the database's liste.

We know it's possible to do that from the SQL query but we are looking for a solution to do that in the connection itself.

We've tried using the DATABASE/DB/SCHEMA but no way, each time Power BI Desktop display us the entire list of database.

Any idea or tricks ?

Comment: Have you tried using the .NET Provider with "native" PBI connector instead?

Comment: you mean the "teradata database" connector ? I've tested using in the sql the command "database mydb" and say native query are not supported.

Comment: You might try setting the UseXViews option to restrict the list to objects on which the user holds some access right.